# How do I determine component with focus in a codenameone container?

Tags: codenameone

I am building a json editor in codenameone. In my current design I need to insert or remove components that have focus when a menu command is pressed. So for instance if i have TextFields inside a Container , I need to determine which textfield has focus when I press the insert menu option so that I can insert another component there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the current form (you can get the current form using `Display.getInstance().getCurrent()`) invoke `getFocused()`. You can also bind a focus listener using `addFocusListener` on the form or on the component you want to track.

Notice that with touch device the concept of focus isn't quite the same since focus isn't marked on such devices.

Comment: If focus is not marked how do i determine which is the current component?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying, there is no such concept in touch devices. Look at a typical Android or iOS UI, notice there is no current component on the device...